# Want to select multiple item in Ccombo box In Tree Editor in SWT

Tags: autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, ccombo

In a Tree Viewer, I have five Columns and  in this columns except first I am using CCombo Box with the help of tree editor. Now in CCombo box I need to select all items. How is it possible? Please find the below code implementation of CCombo box in my view:

```
final CCombo comboForRunOn = new CCombo(remoteTable, SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboForRunOn.setItems(remoteComputerIPs);

/*Exe Type - WINDOWS, ANDROID*/
final CCombo comboForExeType = new CCombo(remoteTable, SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboForExeType.setItems(exeTypes.toArray(new String[exeTypes.size()]));
comboForExeType.select(exeTypes.indexOf(tsTCGson.tcParams.get(1).tcparamValue));
/*Exe Type - Firefox, IE, Chrome*/
final CCombo comboForExePlatform = new CCombo(remoteTable, SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboForExePlatform.setItems(exePlatform.toArray(new String[exePlatform.size()]));
comboForExePlatform.select(exePlatform.indexOf(tsTCGson.tcParams.get(0).tcparamValue));

TreeEditor editorForRunOn = new TreeEditor(remoteTable);
TreeEditor editorForExeType = new TreeEditor(remoteTable);
TreeEditor editorForExePlatform = new TreeEditor(remoteTable);
editorForRunOn.setEditor(comboForRunOn, trtmTestcases, 3);
editorForExeType.setEditor(comboForExeType, trtmTestcases, 2);
editorForExePlatform.setEditor(comboForExePlatform, trtmTestcases, 1);
editorForRunOn.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
editorForRunOn.grabHorizontal = true;
editorForExeType.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT; 
editorForExeType.grabHorizontal = true;
editorForExePlatform.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT; 
editorForExePlatform.grabHorizontal = true;
```

[image]

Comment: CCombo doesn't support multiple selection.

Comment: I would suggest to get simple input which can be supported by swt/jface by asking question at https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this issue i have  create MultiSectionCombo.java class, find the below code,

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

public class MultiSelectionCombo extends Composite {

   Shell shell = null;
   List list = null;

   Text txtCurrentSelection = null;

   String[] textItems = null;
   int[] currentSelection = null;
   TreeItem treeItem = null;

   public MultiSelectionCombo(Composite parent,TreeItem tItem, String[] items, int[] selection, int style) {
      super(parent, style);
      currentSelection = selection;
      textItems = items;
      treeItem = tItem;
      init();
   }

   private void init() {
      GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
      layout.marginBottom = 0;
      layout.marginTop = 0;
      layout.marginLeft = 0;
      layout.marginRight = 0;
      layout.marginWidth = 0;
      layout.marginHeight = 0;
      GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
      gridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
      gridLayout.marginHeight = 0;
      setLayout(gridLayout);
      txtCurrentSelection = new Text(this, SWT.READ_ONLY);
      txtCurrentSelection.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
      txtCurrentSelection.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

      displayText();

      txtCurrentSelection.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

         @Override
         public void mouseDown(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mouseDown(event);
            initFloatShell();
         }

      });
   }

   private void initFloatShell() {
      Point p = txtCurrentSelection.getParent().toDisplay(txtCurrentSelection.getLocation());
      Point size = txtCurrentSelection.getSize();
      Rectangle shellRect = new Rectangle(p.x, p.y + size.y, size.x, 0);
      shell = new Shell(MultiSelectionCombo.this.getShell(), SWT.NO_TRIM);

      GridLayout gl = new GridLayout();
      gl.marginBottom = 0;
      gl.marginTop = 0;
      gl.marginRight = 0;
      gl.marginLeft = 0;
      gl.marginWidth = 0;
      gl.marginHeight = 0;
      shell.setLayout(gl);

      list = new List(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
      for (String value: textItems) {
         list.add(value);
      }

      list.setSelection(currentSelection);

      GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
      list.setLayoutData(gd);

      shell.setSize(shellRect.width, 100);
      shell.setLocation(shellRect.x, shellRect.y);

      list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

         @Override
         public void mouseUp(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mouseUp(event);
            currentSelection = list.getSelectionIndices();
            if ((event.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == 0) {
               shell.dispose();
               displayText();
            }
         }
      });

      shell.addShellListener(new ShellAdapter() {

         public void shellDeactivated(ShellEvent arg0) {
            if (shell != null && !shell.isDisposed()) {
               currentSelection = list.getSelectionIndices();
               displayText();
               shell.dispose();
            }
         }
      });
      shell.open();
   }

   private void displayText() {
      if (currentSelection != null && currentSelection.length > 0) {
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
         for (int i = 0; i < currentSelection.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0)
               sb.append(", ");
            sb.append(textItems[currentSelection[i]]);
         }
         txtCurrentSelection.setText(sb.toString());
         treeItem.setText(1, sb.toString());
      }
      else {
         txtCurrentSelection.setText("");
         treeItem.setText(1,"");
      }
   }

   public int[] getSelections() {
      return this.currentSelection;
   }

}
```

and Its working fine in code.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the CCombo. Was fairly easy, mostly index->Indices. I've marked the more complex things with //mifritscher.

As the original is over 2000 lines, here is just the diff against the original CCombo:

```
--- CCombo.java Sat Feb 25 21:05:43 2023
+++ MultipleSelectionCombo.java Sat Feb 25 21:00:51 2023
@@ -12,13 +12,15 @@
  *     IBM Corporation - initial API and implementation
  *     Paul Pazderski - Bug 349112: allow setting alignment on the text field
  *******************************************************************************/
-package org.eclipse.swt.custom;
+package com.vogella.tycho.plugin2.utils.rcp;
 
 
+import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.function.*;
 
 import org.eclipse.swt.*;
 import org.eclipse.swt.accessibility.*;
+import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel;
 import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
 import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;
 import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
@@ -51,7 +53,7 @@
  * @see <a href="http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php">SWT Example: CustomControlExample</a>
  * @see <a href="http://www.eclipse.org/swt/">Sample code and further information</a>
  */
-public class CCombo extends Composite {
+public class MultipleSelectionCombo extends Composite {
 
    Text text;
    List list;
@@ -99,7 +101,7 @@
  * @see SWT#TRAIL
  * @see Widget#getStyle()
  */
-public CCombo (Composite parent, int style) {
+public MultipleSelectionCombo (Composite parent, int style) {
    super (parent, style = checkStyle (style));
    _shell = super.getShell ();
 
@@ -121,7 +123,7 @@
            arrowEvent (event);
            return;
        }
-       if (CCombo.this == event.widget) {
+       if (MultipleSelectionCombo.this == event.widget) {
            comboEvent (event);
            return;
        }
@@ -148,7 +150,7 @@
        }
        if (event.widget instanceof Control) {
            Shell shell = ((Control)event.widget).getShell ();
-           if (shell == CCombo.this.getShell ()) {
+           if (shell == MultipleSelectionCombo.this.getShell ()) {
                handleFocus (SWT.FocusOut);
            }
        }
@@ -163,7 +165,7 @@
    for (int arrowEvent : arrowEvents)
        arrow.addListener (arrowEvent, listener);
 
-   createPopup(null, -1);
+   createPopup(null, null);
    if ((style & SWT.SIMPLE) == 0) {
        int itemHeight = list.getItemHeight ();
        if (itemHeight != 0) {
@@ -383,6 +385,7 @@
            event.type = SWT.None;
            break;
        }
+       /*- mifritscher: unneeded...
        case SWT.MouseWheel: {
            Point pt = getDisplay ().map (arrow, this, event.x, event.y);
            event.x = pt.x; event.y = pt.y;
@@ -392,13 +395,13 @@
            if (!event.doit) break;
            if (event.count != 0) {
                event.doit = false;
-               int oldIndex = getSelectionIndex ();
+               int oldIndex = getSelectionIndices ();
                if (event.count > 0) {
                    select (Math.max (oldIndex - 1, 0));
                } else {
                    select (Math.min (oldIndex + 1, getItemCount () - 1));
                }
-               if (oldIndex != getSelectionIndex ()) {
+               if (oldIndex != getSelectionIndices ()) {
                    Event e = new Event();
                    e.time = event.time;
                    e.stateMask = event.stateMask;
@@ -408,6 +411,7 @@
            }
            break;
        }
+       */
        case SWT.Selection: {
            text.setFocus();
            dropDown (!isDropped ());
@@ -420,7 +424,9 @@
    String name = getClass ().getName ();
    int index = name.lastIndexOf ('.');
    if (!name.substring (0, index + 1).equals (PACKAGE_PREFIX)) {
+       /*- mifritscher: hmmhmm^^
        SWT.error (SWT.ERROR_INVALID_SUBCLASS);
+       */
    }
 }
 /**
@@ -526,11 +532,12 @@
    checkWidget ();
    text.copy ();
 }
-void createPopup(String[] items, int selectionIndex) {
+void createPopup(String[] items, int[] selectionIndices) {
    // create shell and list
    popup = new Shell (getShell (), SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP);
    int style = getStyle ();
-   int listStyle = SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL;
+   // mifritscher
+   int listStyle = SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI;
    if ((style & SWT.FLAT) != 0) listStyle |= SWT.FLAT;
    if ((style & SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT) != 0) listStyle |= SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT;
    if ((style & SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT) != 0) listStyle |= SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
@@ -547,7 +554,7 @@
        list.addListener (listEvent, listener);
 
    if (items != null) list.setItems (items);
-   if (selectionIndex != -1) list.setSelection (selectionIndex);
+   if (selectionIndices != null) list.setSelection (selectionIndices);
 }
 /**
  * Cuts the selected text.
@@ -621,12 +628,12 @@
    if (!isVisible()) return;
    if (getShell() != popup.getParent ()) {
        String[] items = list.getItems ();
-       int selectionIndex = list.getSelectionIndex ();
+       int[] selectionIndices = list.getSelectionIndices ();
        list.removeListener (SWT.Dispose, listener);
        popup.dispose();
        popup = null;
        list = null;
-       createPopup (items, selectionIndex);
+       createPopup (items, selectionIndices);
    }
 
    Point comboSize = getSize ();
@@ -869,9 +876,9 @@
  *    <li>ERROR_THREAD_INVALID_ACCESS - if not called from the thread that created the receiver</li>
  * </ul>
  */
-public int getSelectionIndex () {
+public int[] getSelectionIndices () {
    checkWidget ();
-   return list.getSelectionIndex ();
+   return list.getSelectionIndices ();
 }
 @Override
 public Shell getShell () {
@@ -1192,10 +1199,10 @@
        case SWT.Dispose:
            if (getShell () != popup.getParent ()) {
                String[] items = list.getItems ();
-               int selectionIndex = list.getSelectionIndex ();
+               int[] selectionIndices = list.getSelectionIndices ();
                popup = null;
                list = null;
-               createPopup (items, selectionIndex);
+               createPopup (items, selectionIndices);
            }
            break;
        case SWT.FocusIn: {
@@ -1226,15 +1233,26 @@
        }
        case SWT.MouseUp: {
            if (event.button != 1) return;
-           dropDown (false);
+           // mifritscher: Allow multi editing
+           if ((event.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == 0 && (event.stateMask & SWT.SHIFT) == 0) {
+               dropDown (false);
+           }
            break;
        }
        case SWT.Selection: {
-           int index = list.getSelectionIndex ();
-           if (index == -1) return;
-           text.setText (list.getItem (index));
+           // mifritscher
+           int[] indices = list.getSelectionIndices ();
+           if (indices == null) return;
+           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
+           for (int i = 0 ; i < indices.length;i++) {
+               sb.append(list.getItem (indices[i]));
+               if (i < indices.length -1) {
+                   sb.append(',');
+               }
+           }
+           text.setText (sb.toString());
            if (text.getEditable() && text.isFocusControl()) text.selectAll ();
-           list.setSelection (index);
+           list.setSelection (indices);
            Event e = new Event ();
            e.time = event.time;
            e.stateMask = event.stateMask;
@@ -1505,27 +1523,34 @@
  * list.  If the item at the index was already selected, it remains
  * selected. Indices that are out of range are ignored.
  *
- * @param index the index of the item to select
+ * @param indices the index of the item to select
  *
  * @exception SWTException <ul>
  *    <li>ERROR_WIDGET_DISPOSED - if the receiver has been disposed</li>
  *    <li>ERROR_THREAD_INVALID_ACCESS - if not called from the thread that created the receiver</li>
  * </ul>
  */
-public void select (int index) {
+public void select (int[] indices) {
    checkWidget();
-   if (index == -1) {
+   //mifritscher: more or less unneeded...
+   if (indices == null) {
        list.deselectAll ();
        text.setText (""); //$NON-NLS-1$
        return;
    }
-   if (0 <= index && index < list.getItemCount()) {
-       if (index != getSelectionIndex()) {
-           text.setText (list.getItem (index));
-           if (text.getEditable() && text.isFocusControl()) text.selectAll ();
-           list.select (index);
-           list.showSelection ();
+   if (!Arrays.equals(indices, getSelectionIndices())) {
+       // mifritscher
+       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
+       for (int i = 0 ; i < indices.length;i++) {
+           sb.append(list.getItem (indices[i]));
+           if (i < indices.length -1) {
+               sb.append(',');
+           }
        }
+       text.setText (sb.toString());
+       if (text.getEditable() && text.isFocusControl()) text.selectAll ();
+       list.select (indices);
+       list.showSelection ();
    }
 }
 
@@ -1855,6 +1880,7 @@
            if (isDisposed ()) break;
            event.doit = keyEvent.doit;
            if (!event.doit) break;
+           /*- mifritscher: not needed
            if (event.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_UP || event.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_DOWN) {
                event.doit = false;
                if ((event.stateMask & SWT.ALT) != 0) {
@@ -1865,13 +1891,13 @@
                    break;
                }
 
-               int oldIndex = getSelectionIndex ();
+               int oldIndex = getSelectionIndices ();
                if (event.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_UP) {
                    select (Math.max (oldIndex - 1, 0));
                } else {
                    select (Math.min (oldIndex + 1, getItemCount () - 1));
                }
-               if (oldIndex != getSelectionIndex ()) {
+               if (oldIndex != getSelectionIndices ()) {
                    Event e = new Event();
                    e.time = event.time;
                    e.stateMask = event.stateMask;
@@ -1879,6 +1905,7 @@
                }
                if (isDisposed ()) break;
            }
+           */
 
            // Further work : Need to add support for incremental search in
            // pop up list as characters typed in text widget
@@ -1956,6 +1983,7 @@
            if (text.getEditable() && text.isFocusControl()) text.selectAll ();
            break;
        }
+       /*- mifritscher: not needed
        case SWT.MouseWheel: {
            notifyListeners (SWT.MouseWheel, event);
            event.type = SWT.None;
@@ -1963,13 +1991,13 @@
            if (!event.doit) break;
            if (event.count != 0) {
                event.doit = false;
-               int oldIndex = getSelectionIndex ();
+               int oldIndex = getSelectionIndices ();
                if (event.count > 0) {
                    select (Math.max (oldIndex - 1, 0));
                } else {
                    select (Math.min (oldIndex + 1, getItemCount () - 1));
                }
-               if (oldIndex != getSelectionIndex ()) {
+               if (oldIndex != getSelectionIndices ()) {
                    Event e = new Event();
                    e.time = event.time;
                    e.stateMask = event.stateMask;
@@ -1979,6 +2007,7 @@
            }
            break;
        }
+       */
        case SWT.Traverse: {
            switch (event.detail) {
                case SWT.TRAVERSE_ARROW_PREVIOUS:
```

The big advantage: it can be used e.g. in a CellEditor quite easiely (Copy `ComboBoxCellEditor` to `MultipleComboBoxCellEditor`, stuff the `AbstractComboBoxCellEditor` in it, change the CCombo Widget and do some trivial int->int[] and Index->Indices exchanges). Or also other SWT/Jface stuff like in a Tree Viewer.

Btw, this patch is public domain, so of somebody would like to get it upstreamed: Go for it :-)